# Angular 4 - SASS Intellisense - vsCode

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Is there any way to enable intellisense in scss file? I'm importing variables into my project, works well, but on each time I must go to _variable.scss file and look what have I write there because it's not suggesting.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I figured out, you need to install in vsCode plugin:

[image]